# Java getting a sum from If statement

Tags: java

I have this assignment:

> Write a Java program which finds all the odd numbers from 1 - 50 which are divisible by 7, but sums only the EVEN numbers which are divisible by 9.
>   Print sum.
>   Print count of odd numbers which are divisible by 7.
>   Print count of even numbers which are divisible by 9 within that range.

This is my code:

```
    int sNumber = 0;
    for(int aNumber= 1; aNumber <= 50; aNumber++)
    {
     if (aNumber % 7 == 0)
      if(aNumber % 2 == 1)                 
       System.out.println("These are odd"+" "+ aNumber);                                
    }            
    for(int bNumber=1 ; bNumber < 50; bNumber++)
    {
     if (bNumber % 9 == 0)
      if(bNumber%2 == 0)                                
       System.out.println("These are even"+" "+bNumber);
    }
```

I'm stuck with putting `bNumbers` into sum form, any help?

Comment: `sNumber += bNumber;`?

Comment: `int sum = 0;` `sum += bNumber;` ?

Comment: Please consider what I have written in my answer and try to understand how it is obtained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to start with creating a variable to store the `sum`. It has to start from 0. Whenever you find an even number that is divisible by 9, you add it to the `sum`. By the end of your `for` loop when you have iterated through all of your numbers, you would have the total of all your even numbers that are divisible by 9 in your variable `sum`.

In my code below, I have also used two integers `countEven` and `countOdd` to keep track of the number of relevant numbers found. `counteven` increments by one whenever an even number that is divisible by 9 is found and `countodd` increments by one whenever an odd number that is divisible by 7 is found.

Note: it is always good practice to use braces for all `for`, `if`, `while` and other similar statements / loops, even if the block contains only one line of code to execute.

```
int countEven = 0, countOdd = 0, sum = 0;

for(int i= 1; i <= 50; i++){

    if ((i % 7 == 0) && (i % 2 == 1)) {
        System.out.println("This is an odd number that is divisible by 7: " + i);
        countOdd++;
    }

    if ((i % 9 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0)) {
        System.out.println("This is an even number that is divisible by 9: " + i);
        countEven++;
        sum += i;
    }
}

System.out.println("These are " + countOdd " odd numbers thare are divisible by 7 and " + countEven + " even numbers that are divisible by 9.");
System.out.println("Sum of even numbers that are divisible by 9: " + sum);
```

Comment: If I can ask a question, why do set int counteven, countodd both at 0 at the beginning; then with the for loop you only needed to do it once? how do you close it when you continue down?; I had the problem when I tried to close and system.out.print to enter in words and variables it would tell me that there was no existent variable.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't quite understand your question. I used `countEven` to count the number of even numbers and `countOdd` to count the number of odd numbers. As such, the two variables serve 2 different purposes. When I find an odd number, I increment `countOdd`, and I do not increment `countEven`. Does this answer your question?

Comment: What do you mean by **close it**?

Comment: **Note:** I declared `countEven` , `countOdd` and `sum` outside of the `for` loop. You **cannot** declare them inside the `for` loop. Variables declared inside the `for` loop go out of scope and cease to exist at the end of each loop iteration! Maybe that is the error you got: 'no existent variable'.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two loops to do this, it can be done in one.

Check the current number vs. the two conditions you have:

```
if(i % 2 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)
    sumOfEven += i;
if(i % 2 != 0 && i % 9 == 0)
    countOdd++;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply add this to your second loop `sNumber += bNumber;`

Also consider using  AND operator instead of nested if statement.

```
int sNumber = 0;
        for (int aNumber = 1; aNumber <= 50; aNumber++) {
            if (aNumber % 7 == 0 && aNumber % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("These are odd" + " " + aNumber);
            }
        }
        for (int bNumber = 1; bNumber <= 50; bNumber++) {
            if (bNumber % 7 == 0 && bNumber % 2 == 1) {
                System.out.println("These are even" + " " + bNumber);
                sNumber += bNumber;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of even numbers" + " " + sNumber);
```

Hope this helps.